# Android Gradle dependency error for "com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.0.0-rcl"?

Tags: java, android, gradle, build.gradle

I'm trying to follow the steps applied in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e6eyN76lRUk&t=222s) to implement "QR Code reader with Firebase ML in real time".

While adding this line in dependencies,

```
    implementation 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.0.0-rcl'
```

I got the following error

```
    ERROR: Failed to resolve: com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.0.0-rcl
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 implementation 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.0.0-rcl'
```

Is that an L on the end ... it  should be 1.

Try:

> implementation 'com.otaliastudios:cameraview:2.0.0-rc1'

Comment: Yes exactly. It was 1 instead of  being L.

Answer (score 0):

Update your project gradle

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }

}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

After clean project and sync gradle again.